# String split based on condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have few string with numbers like this; and its around 3000 records.

```
            Column
            ------------
            Cell 233567-3455
            Cell123-4567
            Cell#123-7449
            Local 456-0987
            1 616 468-7796
            1234567-5x2345
            234/625-1234
            (C)755-7442
            5732878-2
            5721899-23
            6712909-3
            7894200-234
            2144-57238
            5673893/588218
            437-4737-5772
```

How can i find the records like below:

```
            Column
            -------------
            5732878-2
            5721899-23
            6712909-3
            7894200-234
```

Once I find this, I need to split those into two parts

```
            1st Column.    |  2nd column
            -------------  |
            5732878        |   5732872      
            5721899        |   5721823
            6712909        |   6712903
            7894200        |   7894234
```

I tried to fix This using PARINDEX and CHARINDEX
But somehow its not working.Please help.

Comment: What is the logic behind your desired result???   Also post the code of the attempt you made that isn't working so that we can debug it.

Comment: @TabAlleman It looks like the last X chars of the 1st telephone can be replaced by the chars to the right of the hyphen. The middle result set? No idea.

Comment: @dfundako I get that in the second result set, but what is the logic in eliminating the rows that were eliminated in the first result?

Comment: not that I support a guessing game, but it looks like the excluded records simply can't be processed by the logic that says 'swap out the right N characters of the string to the left of the hyphen with the N characters found to the right of the hyphen'  (yuck, what a construction)

Comment: How can you magically put 2 columns side by side??  Is it random???  If not, where's you logic???

Comment: So based on the length of the characters after the hyphen, replace the same characters at the end of the string before the hyphen? I noticed you skipped the `437-4737-5772` value... what logic should we expect there? And what about `2144-57238`?

Comment: Don't forget to upvote all helpful answers and select one as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your filtering logic to get to your intermediate set, but this should get your expected final result set. I assumed you only want records where the length of the string to the left of the hyphen is greater than the length on the right and also exclude records with more than 1 hyphen.

```
SELECT LEFT(telephone, CHARINDEX('-', telephone)-1) AS [1stTelephone],
STUFF(
--get the string before the hyphen
LEFT(telephone, CHARINDEX('-', telephone)-1), 
--get the starting location of chars we are going to replace
LEN(LEFT(telephone, CHARINDEX('-', telephone)))-LEN(RIGHT(telephone, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(telephone))-1)), 
--get the length of the section we are replacing
LEN(RIGHT(telephone, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(telephone))-1)),
--replace that section with the string after the hyphen
RIGHT(telephone, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(telephone))-1)
) AS [2nd telephone]

FROM your_table

WHERE LEN(LEFT(telephone, CHARINDEX('-', telephone))) > LEN(RIGHT(telephone, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(telephone))))
AND len(telephone) - len(REPLACE(telephone, '-', '')) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clue. However, I have some kind of different records as well to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

### DDL

```
use tempdb

create table TelNo (
    Tel varchar(30)
)

insert TelNo(Tel)
values ('5732878-2'),
('5721899-23'),
('6712909-3'),
('7894200-234'),
('2144-57238'),
('5673893/588218'),
('437-4737-5772')
```

### Code

```
select Tel,
    case 
        when Tel like '%_-[0-9]' then left(Tel, len(Tel)-2) 
        when Tel like '%__-[0-9][0-9]' then left(Tel, len(Tel)-3) 
        when Tel like '%___-[0-9][0-9][0-9]' then left(Tel, len(Tel)-4) 
        else Tel 
    end Tel1,
    case 
        when Tel like '%_-[0-9]' then left(Tel, len(Tel)-3) + right(Tel, 1)
        when Tel like '%__-[0-9][0-9]' then left(Tel, len(Tel)-5) + right(Tel, 2)
        when Tel like '%___-[0-9][0-9][0-9]' then left(Tel, len(Tel)-7) + right(Tel, 3)
        else NULL 
    end Tel2
from TelNo
```

Comment: Looks like 2nd case is not working as expected.error showing is : invalid length parameter passed to the left or substring function.

Comment: Can you tell what value you are getting the error on?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat dirty method (looks specifically for 7 digits followed by hyphen followed by any number of digits):

```
SELECT BasePhone AS Phone1, LEFT(BasePhone, 7-LEN(OtherPhoneEnd)) + OtherPhoneEnd AS Phone2
FROM (
    SELECT LEFT(Telephone, 7) AS BasePhone, SUBSTRING(Telephone,9,7) AS OtherPhoneEnd 
    FROM Telephones 
    WHERE Telephone LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-%'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed based on information you given, that you want numbers with hyphen (-) at 8th position. Try this:

```
create table #TelNo (
    Tel varchar(30)
)

insert #TelNo(Tel)
values ('5732878-2'),
('5721899-23'),
('6712909-3'),
('7894200-234'),
('2144-57238'),
('5673893/588218'),
('437-4737-5772')

select Tel, LEFT(Tel, Len(tel) - len(suffix)) + suffix [SecondTel] from (
    select substring(Tel, 1, 7) [Tel], substring(Tel, 9, 10) [suffix] from #TelNo
    where CHARINDEX('-', Tel) = 8
)a
```